# Plotting in sage

Tags: plot, sage

my questions involves the following: I have the basic task of visualizing the steps in a sorting algorithm by plotting the vector as a bar graph. That's no problem and I already have my solution. The only problem is that I consider my solution ugly in the sense, that I always make a call to a plotting function and thus get a new window all the time, resulting in a lot of them.

Question: Can I somehow make a function that takes the previous plot as an argument and plots the graph in the same window? Or something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the Jupyter notebook from within Sage (using a SageMath kernel).  Then you can just reevaluate the cell when you want to update your graph.  Or, if I'm understanding the question correctly, you could have

```
Cell 1 - basic functions
Cell 2 - function that updates graph using P += new_plot syntax
Cell 3 - cell where you do the plotting
```

I'm not certain I've understood, though.

---

Previously:

You should probably try using the Sage notebook.

Comment: Thanks but I switched directly to matplotlib where the default is different.

Comment: Yes, for more pure data plotting mpl is probably the way to go, especially if you can combine it with the new IPython, e.g. http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html

Comment: Link is outdated, can you (or someone) provide a new one?

Comment: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ but also nowadays https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ for the very latest Jupyter experience.